# Is there a limit to filter by category for woocommerce shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I am trying to display woocommerce products on one of my pages, but I want to filter the output by categories. this is my shortcode:`[products limit="3" columns="3" category="armor-lux, truien, jas" cat_operator="AND"]`.

I expected it to display all the products that have the categories "armor-lux", "truien" and "jas" but it displays nothing. But when i remove one of the categories it works. Is there a limit?

Comment: Your shortcode syntax seems to be correct, make sure that the products are visible and the slugs are not misspelled.

Comment: There is no limit… Just remove `cat_operator="AND"` as this is not what you really want. "AND" operator will only display products that belong to all 3 specified categories, instead of "IN" that will display products from each specified category (Default argument is "IN").

Comment: When I change the operator to "IN" it dislpays nothing, I have checked the slugs and those are correct.

Comment: AS the default operator is "IN", just remove `cat_operator="AND"` and remove white spaces between the comma separated term slugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your requirement, This is **very easy**, just change the shortcode parameter

**2 Solution over here**

**First Solution:**

From your shortcode remove parameter **cat_operator="AND"** and code is working perfectly.
Your new Shortcode is `[products limit="3" columns="3" category="armor-lux, truien, jas" cat_operator="AND"]`

**Second Solution**

Instead of your shortcode, Add this shortcode I have edited your shortcode please test

```
[product_category limit="4" columns="3" category="armor-lux, truien, jas"]
```

No need for cat_operator to the shortcode.

Thanks